# What is the difference between reading the document ID using snapshot and context in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following function:

```
exports.logDocId = functions.firestore
    .document("documents/" + "{documentId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      //const docId = snapshot.id; //1.
      //const docId = context.params.documentId; //2.
      console.log(docId);
      //...
    });
```

What is the difference between these two approaches? I'm asking this, because the 1. approach works, while the second one, it doesn't. It always logs `undefined` inside the **emulator**.

Comment: does [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=1st#wildcards-parameters) answer your question? Basically `snapshot` is the new changed data and `context` is where these changes have been made

Comment: @NoNam4 No, it doesn't. If I don't change the the document ID, why the second approach doesn't work in the emulator?

Comment: Does your cloud function really work? because `.document("documents" + "{documentId}")` is not correct. You should have a `/` between the collection and the wildcard.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Apologies, my mistake. Yes, I missed to add the `/`. And yes, it works on the emulator because the first statement returns the correct ID, while the second one is `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: And what do you get if you deploy it ?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec If I don't use the emulator, and I deploy it normally in a Firebase project, both are working perfect.

Comment: Do you start all the emulators?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes, I did start all emulators.

Comment: So I suggest that you create a bug report https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs, adding all the details.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Ok, I will. Did you encounter the same issue?